# MySQL query find and add new rows

Tags: sql, mysql

We have a table "faq_question_store" with two columns "question_id" and "store_id".

We nee to copy all values where "store_id" value is "2" and add new rows but then with the value "4".

So from the following screenshot, we need to copy all rows with "store_id" 2, so it becomes:

```
355 4
354 4
353 4
...
```

How can we achieve this with a query?

[image]

Comment: Did you give anything a try

Comment: Did you learn anything from your previous question about updating this table? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531847/mysql-query-find-and-replace-values-inside-table )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `question_id`'s from the table where the `store_id` is 2 and insert them into your table with a `store_id` of 4.

```
INSERT INTO faq_question_store 
(
  SELECT question_id, 4 AS store_id
  FROM faq_question_store
  WHERE store_id = 2
)
```

Working example: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zq88AOFd)